# Creating security groups from Cloud Formation template fails with "group already exists"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have setup a CF file that creates groups and SQS queues, but when I push it it always fails saying the security group I am creating already exists (which doesn't make any sense):

```
"ApiSecurityGroupProduction": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Group for the api instances",
        "GroupName": "api_production",
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [
            {
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "FromPort": "8000",
                "ToPort": "8000",
                "SourceSecurityGroupId": "sg-843f59ed"
            },
            {
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "FromPort": "22",
                "ToPort": "22",
                "SourceSecurityGroupName": "chef_server"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And it fails with:

```
14:20:38 UTC-0300   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup ApiSecurityGroupProduction  api_production already exists
```

This event is generated just after the create for this same group. Why would this happen here? is there some other config I have to setup here to make it work?

Comment: Could you paste or link to more of your CF template? Especially any other security groups.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mauricio/23fc9adc6f73bf20e4aa

Comment: Your template looks fine. If you really don't have an SGs with the same name in the same AWS account then I'd open a ticket if you have support.

Comment: Thanks, gonna do that!

Comment: While not the case in this instance, it is possible to get this error message when the same GroupName is created multiple times by the template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end the problem was the `GroupName` property, once it was removed the group was correctly created.